# Merging identically built MySQL tables with non-identical information

Tags: mysql

I have 8 tables, and all of the tables have exactly the same structure. Column 1 on each of the tables is ID and it's int, primary key, auto-increment

Would the correct thing to do be to create a 9th table with the same structure as the other 8, and then `INSERT * FROM table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, table7 table8 INTO table9 EXCEPT ID`

I'm really very unsure how to go about doing this. I've just spent all day pulling data from 15 years worth of Excel files and creating the tables by hand, with the help of PHPMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench.

So any tips to put this task to a quick end will be greatly appreciated (and you SQL guys do NOT get paid enough)

Comment: Have you tried it?  You might have to do them one at a time, but that sounds like a reasonable way to go.  I believe the syntax you want is known as [Insert-Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Insert-Select statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) plus [UNION statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
INSERT INTO table9(all, coma, separated, fields, except, id) 
SELECT all, coma, separated, fields, except, id FROM table1 UNION
SELECT all, coma, separated, fields, except, id FROM table2 UNION
...
SELECT all, coma, separated, fields, except, id FROM table8;
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed I would go for an Insert-into as Sergey suggested.

However I wouldn't go for a UNION. The UNION documentation says:

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result

You're mixing different tables (and even removing their ids) so if you have this in table1:

```
id | nonIdField_1 | nonIdField_2, etc
-------------------------------------
1  | A            | B
```

and this in table2

```
id | nonIdField_1 | nonIdField_2, etc
-------------------------------------
5  | A            | B
```

The result would be:

```
nonIdField_1 | nonIdField_2, etc
--------------------------------
A            | B
```

And I think you want this (In order not to lose information):

```
nonIdField_1 | nonIdField_2, etc
--------------------------------
A            | B
A            | B
```

So you should use a UNION ALL instead of a UNION. That former will not remove duplicates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thats a good tip, thanks for looking out for that. I'll definitely look and see if I've lost any information.